# Javascript select individual option

Tags: javascript

I have been trying lately to make a function that on change on the select box it return only the selected option value.

My markup looks like this:

```
<select id='rangeSelector'>
    <option value='custom'>Custom</option>
    <option value='7 days'>7 days</option>
    <option value='14 days'>14 days</option>
    <option value='WTD'>WTD</option>
    <option value='MTD'>MTD</option>
    <option value='QTD'>QTD</option>
    <option value='YTD'>YTD</option>
</select>
```

and the javascript function:

```
var rangeSelector = document.getElementById('rangeSelector');
rangeSelector.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    var x = rangeSelector.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        var newX = x[i].value;
        console.log(newX);
    }   
}, false);
```

What I am trying to do is when I click on 7 days to return only 7 days.

Comment: Just `console.log(this.value);`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hLwz60n5/

Comment: Thank you very much. it solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var rangeSelector = document.getElementById('rangeSelector');
 rangeSelector.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
       console.log(rangeSelector.value);
    }, true);
```

You do not need for loop for that, after firing event "change" `rangeSelector.value` already have value of chosen element.

so if you wanna add "active" to selected option you can do same:

```
     var rangeSelector = document.getElementById('rangeSelector');
     rangeSelector.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
         var x = rangeSelector.children;
         var y = rangeSelector.selectedIndex;
         x[y].className = x[y].className + " active";
         console.log(rangeSelector.value);
     }, true);
```

but you should remove "active" class from all non-active, by looping them:)

```
     var rangeSelector = document.getElementById('rangeSelector');
     rangeSelector.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
         var x = rangeSelector.children;
         var y = rangeSelector.selectedIndex;
         for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
             x[i].className = "";  //or x[i].removeAttribute("class");`
         }   
         x[y].className = x[y].className + " active";
         console.log(rangeSelector.value);
     }, true);
```

Comment: thank you very much, but this add active class to all of them, it dosen't toggle the class based on wich option is active

Comment: I just added fix for this.

Comment: i do not have experience with this but is it normal that when you swich classes to active the html attribute class appereas as empty ?

Comment: You can add some logic to this and can just remove attribute ` x[i].removeAttribute("class");`, but I think it will not so fast as just make it empty.

Comment: I'd change last code in answer where you can decide: delete attribute "class" or delete "class" value

Answer (score 2):

Don't read the `<option>`s. Read the `<select>`.

```
document.getElementById('rangeSelector').value
```

Other interesting bits include `.selectedIndex` and `.selectedOptions`.

(Of course, as Abhitalks notes in the comments, in your handler, the element getting will already done for you.)

Comment: and let's say depending on the selcted value is it possible to add and active class ? and if so how can i achive that

Comment: Of course it's possible. What exactly would you set, and where?

Comment: if i select the 7days option the <option> tag to be something like <option class='active'> and so on

Comment: For that you should get index of element by `document.getElementById('rangeSelector').selectedIndex` and then:     `var x = rangeSelector.children;
    var y = rangeSelector.selectedIndex;
    x[y].addAttribute(foo);`

Comment: Just look my answer there are a simple code for doing this.

Comment: @DragosPodaru: Why would you want to do that in the first place? When you select any option in the select it gets the `selected` property set to true anyway. Use that for your css rules if required. Adding a class would be redundant at best.

Comment: Indeed. I thought you want to apply a class to something *else* based on the selection. It makes little sense to put a class on the *option*.

Comment: i want to display other divs based on the selected value, but i was not aware of the :selected property

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this, example:

```
$("#rangeSelector").on("change", function() {
    var rangeSelect = document.getElementById("rangeSelector");
    var value = selectJaar.options[rangeSelect.selectedIndex].value;
    return value;
});
```

This first gets the dropdown, then get the selected value, and return it.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply using `this.value`:

```js
document.getElementById('rangeSelector').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  alert(this.value);
});
```

```html
<select id='rangeSelector'>
  <option value='custom'>Custom</option>
  <option value='7 days'>7 days</option>
  <option value='14 days'>14 days</option>
  <option value='WTD'>WTD</option>
  <option value='MTD'>MTD</option>
  <option value='QTD'>QTD</option>
  <option value='YTD'>YTD</option>
</select>
```